# How to change the cursor type over a specific region of an image

Tags: matlab, user-interface, mouse-cursor

I would like to know, in a MATLAB GUI, how to pre-define a region of interest in an image, that

- when the user passes the mouse over the region, the cursor type changes the type of pointer from an arrow to a hand
- when the pointer is already in the type of a hand, the user can click on it and perform some part of the code.

I hope I'm stating my question correctly, I've been trying to find some information about this topic, with no luck.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/specifying-the-figure-pointer.html) will be helpfull, or [this one](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-mouse-pointer-functions/)